# Как в консоли посмотреть нагрузку от MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Друзья, подскажите как в консоли посмотреть нагрузку от MySQL? Хостер (VPS) частенько ругается

> *mysql создает сильную нагрузку на дисковую систему корневого сервера*
> и присылает табличку с параметрами: PID, RDDSK,WRDSK,WCANCL

Я тут поаманил с параметрами MySQL и хотел бы глянуть лучше стало или нет, а вот как?

Answer (score 1):

Перейдите в консольный клиент `mysql` и используйте команды:

```
show processlist;
show status;
```

И уже дальше анализируйте.

Касательно **pid**, то это процесс созданный демоном `mysqld`. Какую нагрузку он создает можно посмотреть командой **top**.

**P.S1:** Думаю, наиболее правильный ответ Вам смогут дать на `admin.hashcode.ru`.

**P.S2:** Странно, я всегда думал, арендовал `VPS` и гружу, что хочу и как хочу (в принципе, довольно часто использую VPS и ни разу никто мне замечание не делал; на то это и выделенный сервер, хоть и виртуальный)

Comment: странно, но ничего не подошло, может у меня не та консоль?) (использую консоль в winscp при соединении ssh)

Comment: Консоль везде одна. Подключитесь к VPS, введите команду  mysql -u root -p и у вас потребует пароль для подключения к БД. Введите пароль, вы войдет и уже сможете вводить команды show processlist; show status; и т.д